# MariaDB/PostreSQL - Query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, query-optimization, mariadb

I need to produce some numbers, I have designed a query to get the result desired by my "customers".
This query is based on a table that contains one million records.
I usually use MariaDB for that, and I get a result in ~ 7s.
This execution time is quite suitable but I am looking to optimize again to improve my skills.
After some research, I came across a few posts saying "MySQL is fine, but not on tables> 1M of records, you have to switch on something else" PostgreSQL has been quoted several times.
So I installed PostgreSQL, and copied my tables, indexes and data.
I executed the same query, and I had a result in ~ 12s

I know less PostgreSQL, I think I did not use the specificities inherent to the language.
So for now I stay on MariaDB. Do you have an idea to improve the execution time?

Here my query :

```
select categorie.cat
,dhu_type.type
,COUNT(DISTINCT(
    CASE WHEN dhu.date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31'    
    THEN dhu.id
    END )

  ) AS "2013"
,COUNT(DISTINCT(
    CASE WHEN dhu.date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'    
    THEN dhu.id
    END )

  ) AS "2014"
,COUNT(DISTINCT(
    CASE WHEN dhu.date between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'     
    THEN dhu.id
    END )

  ) AS "2015"
,COUNT(DISTINCT(
    CASE WHEN dhu.date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'       
    THEN dhu.id
    END )

  ) AS "2016"
from dhu
inner join dhu_type on dhu.type_id = dhu_type.id
inner join patient on dhu.patient_id=patient.id
inner join fa on patient.id = fa.patient_id
inner join categorie on categorie.id = fa.cat_id
group by cat,dhu_type.type
```

I complete my question with a diagram

[image]

Here the CREATE TABLE :

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categorie` (
  `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'neonat',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`cat`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cp` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cp` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cp` (`cp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4096 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhu` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `patient_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `type_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_dhu_patient` (`patient_id`),
  KEY `FK_dhu_dhu_type` (`type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_dhu_dhu_type` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `dhu_type` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_dhu_patient` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patient` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=953590 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhu_import` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `noip` bigint(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `cp` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `noip` (`noip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhu_type` (
  `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dpt` (
  `dpt` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `abrev` char(3) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fa` (
  `patient_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`patient_id`,`cat_id`),
  KEY `idx_cat_id_pat_id` (`cat_id`,`patient_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_fa_patient` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patient` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_fa_categorie` FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES `categorie` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fa_import` (
  `noip` bigint(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `cat` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`noip`,`cat`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `patient` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `noip` bigint(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `cp_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_patient_cp` (`cp_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_patient_cp` FOREIGN KEY (`cp_id`) REFERENCES `cp` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=262141 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

Here the explain query :
[image]

Here a modification improving performance (select categorie.id instead of categorie.cat):

[image]

Here the best best query I found thanks @RickJames & @BillKarwin

```
select categorie.cat
,dhu_type.`type`
,t.`2013`
,t.`2014`
,t.`2015`
,t.`2016` 
from ( select fa.cat_id as catid
,dhu.type_id typid
,COUNT(DISTINCT(
    CASE WHEN dhu.date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31'    
    THEN dhu.id
    END )

  ) AS "2013"
,COUNT(DISTINCT(
    CASE WHEN dhu.date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'    
    THEN dhu.id
    END )

  ) AS "2014"
,COUNT(DISTINCT(
    CASE WHEN dhu.date between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'     
    THEN dhu.id
    END )

  ) AS "2015"
,COUNT(DISTINCT(
    CASE WHEN dhu.date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'       
    THEN dhu.id
    END )

  ) AS "2016"
from dhu
inner join patient on dhu.patient_id=patient.id
inner join fa on patient.id = fa.patient_id
group by fa.cat_id, dhu.type_id ) t

inner join categorie on t.catid = categorie.id
inner join dhu_type on t.typid = dhu_type.id

order by categorie.cat,dhu_type.`type`
```

Comment: Do inner join fa, patient, categorie instead.

Comment: You're right, the query is more readable but the excution time is same.

Comment: Conditional aggregation / FILTER #GIYF

Comment: Could you post your tables/data (including any indexes) on sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com and then reply to this comment? Also, have you tried using EXPLAIN?

Comment: Please run ANALYZE TABLE on mysql, VACUUM ANALYZE on postgres, post table definitions, EXPLAIN query on mysql, EXPLAIN ANALYZE on postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- MySQL does just fine with billion-row tables.
- *Any* database engine is at the mercy of the speed of the disk and how much (or little) RAM you have for caching.
- The textbooks say to normalize everything, but I suggest that a 4-char `type` is not worth normalizing.  Ditto for the 5-char `cp`.
- Unless you really want output rows with all zeros, add this `WHERE dhu.date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'` before the `GROUP BY`.
- Follow my advice [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on many:many schema design (`fa`).  This *may* speed up the query for MySQL.  (I don't know if the same principles apply to Postgres.)

Comment: Thanks.  I removed the items you dealt with, and added several more.

Comment: I added the "reverse" index (cat_id,patient_id) but there is no impact.I had never thought of using this, thanks for your advice ;) I cannot use a `WHERE YEAR(dhu.date) = 2016` because i need to count on the range [2013-01-01 ; 2016-12-31]  I think the excution time only come from my virtual machine (Centos/1Go RAM) running on Desktop.  Sadness....

Comment: I might spot something else if you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: I found something ! The execution time is now ~2s with a tiny modification : `SELECT categorie.id,dhu_type.type [...] GROUP BY categorie.id,dhu_type.type ` The `EXPLAIN` is the same than before, i edited my question. But why ?

Comment: You have 3 cases of what you put in the `SELECT` list:  `*`, `cat`, `id`.  `id` will be the fastest, since it is readily available in the index being used; `*` is worst since it requires hauling around all the columns.  This is an example of (1) don't use `*` (unless you need all), (2) when asking a forum question, use the real query, not some 'simplified' version.

Comment: I add the "tuned" query in my question, but i don't understand why it is better, I simply extract a `inner join` from a subquery. Why the engine doesn't optimize the first query like the second ?

Comment: FWIW, the design of pulling an attribute out into a lookup table indexed by an auto-increment is *not* normalization. It has nothing to do with any of the normal forms.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Does the technique have a name?

Comment: I don't know any name for it, besides "making a lookup table indexed by an auto-increment." :-)

Comment: OK, I'll call it MALTIBAAI.  ;)

Comment: Do you think we can do better on this query ?

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the MALTIBAAI for `type`?  That would eliminate a `JOIN` that is critical to the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I tried  the MALTIBAAI on the `dhu_type.id`, very effective ^^ the execution time is now ~1.5s. I will apply this technique in the future, thanks a lot !

Comment: @LoïcDiBenedetto - This technique is practical for "small", relatively-static, things like "type", "country_code", etc.  It may not be practical or effective on bigger things.

Comment: I guess Maltibaai is an Indian singer.